# Angular - Material/Autocomplete Not Displaying As Expected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am attempting to work with the Angular/Material autocomplete component.  I have added the following to my HTML file:

```
<form class="search-form">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Assemblies" matInput [formControl]="assemblySearchControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let assembly of filteredAssemblies" [value]="assembly.id">
                {{assembly.assemblyName}} ({{assembly.referenceNumber}})
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And in my TS file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.assemblySearchControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
      term => {
        if (term != '') {
          this.filteredAssemblies = this._filterAssemblies(term);
        }
      }
    )
  }

private _filterAssemblies(value: string) {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    var temp = this.allAssemblies.filter(assembly => 
        assembly.assemblyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0 || 
        assembly.referenceNumber.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
    console.log("filteredAssemblies: ", temp);
    return temp;
}
```

If I run the site, and type something into the search box, I can see in the Google Chrome console that `filteredAssemblies` has the correct results from the search.  However, the following two problems are occurring:

1. The placeholder text of "Search Assemblies" is not being cleared.  Anything I type in the input field is just being displayed over the placeholder text.
2. The option list with the results stored in `filterAssemblies` is not being shown.

I've tried various solutions online however the same two issues listed above remain.  There are no issues being reported and the code compiles fine.  Is this possibly just a format/layout issue?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to create stackblitz for yor case ?

Comment: If I used the example project on Stackblitz (and create static data) it works fine...but on my actual site, even just clicking in the input box does not cause the label to move/shrink above the text being entered.  Unfortunately I can't put the actual site code into Stackblitz because of its complexity.

Comment: Have you tried as in https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview says, using async pipe instead of subscribe in component ts file? Take a look to the second example, is the same as yours and it's using the async pipe for valuechanges Observable and apply filters